# Nested XML export of parent/child data from Access

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

```
Public Sub Click()

    Dim objOtherTbls As AdditionalData

        Set objOtherTbls = Application.CreateAdditionalData
        objOtherTbls.Add "vessels"
        objOtherTbls.Add "Export"

        Application.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportTable, _
                    DataSource:="orderSummary", _
                    DataTarget:="pls.xml", _
                    AdditionalData:=objOtherTbls


End Sub
```

[image]

How do I make the XML nested and the duplicate fields repeating only once?

```
I would like something like:

 <vessels>
    <vessels ID>
        <product Id>
         <quantity>
        <product Id>
         <quantity> 
        <product Id>
         <quantity>
```

How do i merge the tables and make them like mentioned above, in order to only have each vessel name once and all of the items of that vessel listed below and tabbed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access uses "Relationships" to identify a parent/child hierarchy when exporting to XML. Your database is apparently missing the Relationship between [vessels] and [Export], so you get a "flat" XML export of the two tables as you show in the question.

If you add the Relationship to the database ...

[image: Relationships.png]

... then you will get the "nested" XML export that you seek:

```xml
<vessels>
  <vessel_id>2</vessel_id>
  <vessel_name>B</vessel_name>
</vessels>
<vessels>
  <vessel_id>3</vessel_id>
  <vessel_name>C</vessel_name>
  <Export>
     <product_id>10</product_id>
     <Quantity>10</Quantity>
     <vessel_id>3</vessel_id>
  </Export>
  <Export>
     <product_id>100</product_id>
     <Quantity>20</Quantity>
     <vessel_id>3</vessel_id>
  </Export>
  <Export>
     <product_id>1000</product_id>
     <Quantity>1</Quantity>
     <vessel_id>3</vessel_id>
  </Export>
  <Export>
     <product_id>10000</product_id>
     <Quantity>10</Quantity>
     <vessel_id>3</vessel_id>
  </Export>
  <Export>
     <product_id>10001</product_id>
     <Quantity>20</Quantity>
     <vessel_id>3</vessel_id>
  </Export>
  <Export>
     <product_id>10002</product_id>
     <Quantity>10</Quantity>
     <vessel_id>3</vessel_id>
  </Export>
</vessels>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's quick a sketch (the SQL DDL requires ANSI-92 Query Mode but can be reproduced using the Access GUI tools):

```
CREATE TABLE vessels
( vessel_id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
  vessel_name CHAR(1) WITH COMPRESSION NOT NULL UNIQUE );

CREATE TABLE Export
( product_id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
  Quantity INT NOT NULL, CHECK ( Quantity >= 0 ),
  vessel_id INT NOT NULL 
     REFERENCES vessels ( vessel_id ) );

INSERT INTO vessels VALUES ( 1, 'A' );
INSERT INTO vessels VALUES ( 2, 'B' );
INSERT INTO vessels VALUES ( 3, 'C' );
INSERT INTO vessels VALUES ( 4, 'D' );
INSERT INTO vessels VALUES ( 5, 'E' );

INSERT INTO Export VALUES ( 10, 10, 3 );
INSERT INTO Export VALUES ( 100, 20, 3 );
INSERT INTO Export VALUES ( 1000, 1, 3 );
INSERT INTO Export VALUES ( 10000, 10, 3 );
INSERT INTO Export VALUES ( 10001, 20, 3 );
INSERT INTO Export VALUES ( 10002, 10, 3 );
```